# Are there any Martells still alive?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire, adaptation-comparison

According to the Game of Thrones [Wikia page on House Martell](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/House_Martell) there are no more people named Martell alive. The only descendants of the Prince of Dorne are 5 of his bastard daughters, who aren't named Martell but Sand as is usual for bastards born in Dorne.

Are there any people named Martell still alive?

Comment: The wiki page is about the TV Show. The fate of Martells is different in the books. If you only want answer from tv-show, remove ASOIAF tag.

Comment: @Kepotx I'd like an answer for both

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Note:** The following contains spoilers for ASOS and ADWD. Do not read any further unless you wish to be spoiled.

---

## Books

In the Books, House Martell is very much alive and thriving.

#### Legitimate

We have legitimate members like:

1. Prince [Doran Nymeros Martell](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Doran_Martell)
2. Princess [Arianne Nymeros Martell](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Arianne_Martell) (Heir to Dorne)
3. Prince [Trystane Nymeros Martell](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Trystane_Martell)
4. Ser [Manfrey Martell](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Manfrey_Martell) (Castellan, distant relative)

#### Bastards

Other than them, we have illegitimate members i.e. the Sandsnakes. They are:

1. [Obara Sand](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Obara_Sand)
2. [Nymeria Sand](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Nymeria_Sand)
3. [Tyene Sand](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Tyene_Sand)
4. [Sarella Sand](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Sarella_Sand)
5. [Elia Sand](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Elia_Sand)
6. [Obella Sand](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Obella_Sand)
7. [Dorea Sand](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Dorea_Sand)
8. [Loreza Sand](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Loreza_Sand)

And I'd like to point out that Prince Doran Martell did not sire any bastard daughters that we know of. The bastard daughters were fathered by his brother, Prince Oberyn Martell. Oberyn Martell is a Prince of Dorne, but the *a* in *a Prince of Dorne* makes all the difference. He is a Prince of Dorne whereas his elder brother, that is Doran, is *the Prince of Dorne*.

Answer (score 16):

<sub>Some of the images contain graphic/violent images so they're hidden behind spoiler tags. Look at your own risk.</sub>

---

## Game of Thrones

Per show canon no, every Martell we've seen has been killed, though to be honest we didn't have many in the first place.

**Doran Martell**

He was the head of House Martell and the Prince of Dorne but when he failed action on Oberyn's death Ellaria Sand kills him.

[image: Ellaria kills Dorab]

**Trystane Martell**

He was the son of Doran but was murdered by the Sand Snakes.

[image: Sand Snakes challenge Trystane]

**Oberyn Martell**

Killed by the Mountain in a trial by combat for Tyrion, has a permanent headache.

> [image: Oberyn and Mountain after fight]

**Elia Martell**

Was killed by Ser Gregor Clegane during the Sack of King's Landing at the end of Robert's Rebellion.

---

#### Sand Snakes

We also have the Sand Snakes to talk about who were Oberyn's bastard daughters, however, of the 3 in the show they are all dead.

**Obara Sand**

She is killed by Euron Greyjoy when he attacks the ship they are on.

> [image: Euron kills Obara]

**Nymeria Sand**

Again killed by Euron during the same attack.

> [image: Nymeria Sand death]

**Tyene Sand**

Although she could technically still be alive it's unlikely as she was poisoned by Cersei Lannister in the dungeons at the Red Keep after being taken prisoner by Euron Greyjoy.

[image: Tyene Sand in the dungeons with Ellaria Sand]

**Ellaria Sand**

She was the paramour of Oberyn Martell so technically counts for the House and was the leader of the Sand Snakes. After being caught by Euron Greyjoy she is held prisoner in the Red Keep dungeons in the same cell as her daughter Tyene Sand who has been poisoned. She is to watch her daughter die and then be starved to death. The actress has confirmed her death too (though most likely true who knows? If it's not on screen it's uncertain).

> *How did you find out about Ellaria Sand’s fate?*
>   [Showrunners David Benioff and Dan Weiss] called me, but I kind of knew already. Obviously there’s lots of trimming going on. It’s all coming to a head and you have to get rid of less important characters that the audience hasn’t had the chance to invest in as much. So I was expecting it. I wasn’t heartbroken. And I was like, “As long as I die on screen…” and they were like “Yeah!” But of course I don’t die on screen. I stay alive, I’m just not going to reappear. I think it’s really clever.
>   <sub>[Entertainment Weekly, Game of Thrones actress on her 'worst nightmare' Cersei scene](http://ew.com/tv/2017/07/30/game-of-thrones-ellaria-cersei/)</sub>

Comment: 10/10 for _permanent headache_

Comment: The Martells and Sand Snakes we've seen are killed, but are there indeed no other Martells or Sand Snakes?

Comment: @BCLC None mentioned in the show that I know of and as per show canon if it isn't mentioned it's likely not to have existed. Of course there are others in the books but who knows if they were in show canon?

Comment: Oh. It took me a while to understand that the spoiler tags aren't for spoilers but for violence here.

Comment: @EricDuminil Yeah I'll edit that to be clearer

Comment: Maybe Quentin will pop up later in the show as surprise guest to save the day.

Comment: @CptEric I doubt it and as he's dead in the books I doubt it even more

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot we have so many dead(and alive) people in the books not dead in the show or not even existing that i no longer think that is a good lever of "what will be next". Griff & young griff will agree with me on that.

Comment: @CptEric I know but characters only emerge when needed in showverse and a Martell isn't needed, especially considering the show effectively ignores Dorne all together

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot true, but they could be put up as "Quentyn saves the day against turncloak cersei"-ish of argument.but dunno. we've got a greyjoy, a griff, and angry reachmans too for that task.

Comment: I suppose it's possible he specifically could come to the rescue of Ellaria (he might have some familial interest in saving her, as opposed to any of the other non-present characters)

Comment: @DoktorJ According to the interview I linked Ellaria is dead and so Tyene is probably dead too.

Comment: @BCLC There's absolutely nothing in the show aside from these characters. The show does not even reference any other Houses in Dorne, and Sunspear which would be the seat of House Martell is simply renamed "Dorne". They did a pretty deliberate job of removing all nuance regarding this story arc, so that it's more obviously DONE.